Template errors after upgrading to 5.80.1
I'm getting these errors after upgrading to 5.80.1 on Drupal 7:
Warning: Undefined array key "listingURL" in include() (line 28 of /home/username/www/address.com/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%7F/7F9/7F984A8A%%View.tpl.php).
Warning: Undefined array key "mapURL" in include() (line 32 of /home/username/www/address.com/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%7F/7F9/7F984A8A%%View.tpl.php).

This is after submitting a public profile form.
I've cleared caches, deleted cached templates. Any suggestions?

You can either:

Submit a PR that fixes it. It's probably something like this should be assigned some value regardless of whether the user has permissions or not.

Set your php.ini error_reporting in your web hosting to be E_ERROR (or 1), so that you don't see warnings on a live site.


